# Not able to load data into partitioned table in hive

Tags: hadoop

I am not able to load data into the partitioned table as it is showing "Dynamic partition strict mode requires at least one static partition column. To turn this off set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
" the above error  even on setting set hive.exec.dynamite.partition.mode=nonstrict;
hive> set hive.exec.dynamite.partition=true;
 these parameter i am getting the same error.

Kindly suggest me the better solution.

Thanks in advance;

Comment: Can you post your DDL and INSERT statements pls?

Answer (score 2):

You have various typos (and an interesting affinity to blowing things up):

```
hive.exec.dynamite.partition.mode=nonstrict
```

should be

```
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
```

So, change **dynamite** to **dynamic** (/stop destroying things ;))  and see if you can make better progress.

Answer (score 0):

yeah typos can be a very dangerous thing.

With previous versions of hive(0.12 and previous) hive doesn't validate the hints that you write. Basically you can write anything and hive wont complain. It will only pick the correct ones.

However hive 0.13 onwards, Hive verifies the hints. if something is not correct hive will simply throw an error(Boss check the parameter you have set)